# CSS3: add style if there are no children

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I'm trying to write a scss selector that will add style to the `header-cart` class but only when it doesn't have content inside.

I can use JS, but I think it is possible to write it in scss.

Before AJAX loaded:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right header-cart-dropdown">
  <div class="header-cart">
 
  </div>
</div>
```

After AJAX loaded:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right header-cart-dropdown">
  <div class="header-cart">
   
    <div class="offcanvas-content-container">
      <div class="offcanvas-cart">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I have managed to write something like this, but it does not work correctly:

```
  .dropdown-menu > {
        div {
            &:not(.has-element-loader:has(.offcanvas-content-container)) {
                border: 5px solid green;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:empty` pseudo-class:

```css
.dropdown-menu > div.header-cart:not(:empty) {
      border: 5px solid green;
}

.dropdown-menu > div.header-cart:empty {
      border: 5px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right header-cart-dropdown">
  <div class="header-cart"></div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right header-cart-dropdown">
  <div class="header-cart"> 
    <div class="offcanvas-content-container">
      <div class="offcanvas-cart"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This shows that an empty div would receive the pink border, while a div with content would receive a green border.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use :empty pseudo-class

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty#:~:text=The%20%3Aempty%20CSS%20pseudo%2Dclass,an%20element%20is%20considered%20empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty#:%7E:text=The%20%3Aempty%20CSS%20pseudo%2Dclass,an%20element%20is%20considered%20empty).